# Read csv file hosted on Google Drive

Tags: r, csv, curl, web

I am trying to access (read into R) a .csv file hosted on Google Drive (NOT a Drive spreadsheet) -- having set file permission to 'publicly shareable'.

So based on the shareable URL:

```
sURL <-"https://drive.google.com/file....view?pli=1"
```

I have been trying to read in using:

```
library(curl)
x <- curl(sURL)
data <- read.csv(x)
```

I'm getting this error message:

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
> more columns than column names

Any idea what the complaint is about? Thanks guys.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show us the first few lines of the file?

Comment: @ Richard: original file uploaded to Drive has column names `var1`, `var2`,`var3`,...ect. Is that sufficient?

Comment: The complaint says, well, there are more column names than column fields. Like in `read.csv(text = "col1,col2\n1,2,2,2")`, where `1` is the row name for row #1 and the 3 `2`s are fields values; but there are only two column headers defined. Ergo: error..

Comment: @lukeA: the local .csv is sound (columns/value all in order). The error msg appears only when reading the same .csv doc from the web (Google Drive).

Comment: @ lukeA: Thanks so much. This is what was needed: parse the `id` from the URL then paste it to the address with `..&export=download`. So `curl` is not needed. Guess will have to regex to automate the process.

Comment: I posted it as an answer so that you can mark this question as closed, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try it like this

```
id <- "0B-wuZ2XMFIBUd09Ob0pKVkRzQTA" # google file ID
read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id))
```

Comment: @ lukeA: thanks again. If any idea why `curl` doesn't work, please share.

Comment: `curl` works like this: `library(curl); id <- "0B-wuZ2XMFIBUd09Ob0pKVkRzQTA"; sURL <- sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id); con <- curl(sURL); read.csv(con)`. It returns a connection, not a text file.

Comment: @ lukeA: thanks again again :-). This solved some problems.