# Getting a csv read into R though a shareable google drive link

Tags: r, csv, import

Although [**this response**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135060/read-csv-file-hosted-on-google-drive) seems to be a bit relevant (using a package), I'm wondering how I can use **R BASE** to import a **csv file** using a **shareable google drive link** into R studio?

There are **two columns** in my csv file and **two column names** (namely "dd" and "yy"). But no row.names.

Presently, I'm trying the **following R code** (with no success):

```
 myurl <- "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5V8AyEFBTmXM1VIYUYxSG5tSjQ/view?usp=sharing"


read.csv(url(myurl), header = T, row.names = F)
```

The error I'm getting is:

**`Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names`**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was indicated in the post you linked. Namely,

```
id <- "0B5V8AyEFBTmXM1VIYUYxSG5tSjQ"
stuff <- read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id))
```

Comment: Nah, sprintf is something you probably haven't seen before if you've never done C programming. Basically you have a wildcard `%s` that says there's going to be a string variable after this that I want you to put here. A more conventional "R" approach to it would be: `read.csv(paste0("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=",id,"&export=download"))
`

Comment: Wow, so this also works for an .R file shared with someone and than that person can `source()` the shareable google drive link and run your .R from a distance?

Comment: That is correct as long as the correct permissions are set up on the Google Sheet. For this sheet, it should be since I was able to view it.