# Reading a .por dataset into R from google drive

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, url, import

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42461914/7223434), I'm trying to read a `.por` file into R via a shareable link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/124WOY4iBXxv_9eBXsoHJVUzX98x2sxYy/view?usp=sharing) without success (using `haven` package):

`Error in df_parse_por_file(spec, encoding = "", user_na = user_na, cols_skip`

Is this fixable?

Tried the following:

```
library(haven) 
id <- '124WOY4iBXxv_9eBXsoHJVUzX98x2sxYy'
j <- sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id)

dta <- haven::read_por(j)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `googledrive` package to download the file first:

```
library(googledrive)
googledrive::drive_download('https://drive.google.com/file/d/124WOY4iBXxv_9eBXsoHJVUzX98x2sxYy/view?usp=sharing','test.por',overwrite=T)
dta <- haven::read_por('test.por')
```