# R about assign new labels to the old data when two criteria are met

Tags: r

I am working on a question to assign new labels to the old ones. The question asks me to

1. Add a label '-H1' to every Whole Foods Market at zipcode 94107
2. Add a label '-H2' to every Safeway at zipcode 94107
3. Add a label '-H3' to every Pizzeria Delfina at zipcode 94110

Below is what I have done but it shows error message as "In if (problem$pickup_zipcode == 94107 & problem$pickup_name == : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

[image]

I guess I can not use if because it will not proceed to the next statement? What about "for" instead?

Comment: See [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please do not post code as an image. While we can't test to see if it's the only problem, you should not be using the `assign()` function at all in this case. Use `<-` to assign a value to a variable (`==` is used to test for equality, not assignment).

Comment: You shouldn't use assign for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47443055/3817004) posted so far claims to be a `data.table` approach but replaces every single item hardcoded. Therefore, I feel obliged to post an alternative solution which uses a *lookup table* and an *update on join*:

```
library(data.table)

# read data from google drive
DT <- fread("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1DEdJvAdACVv_Pc5IcgFBSGvDKm_GPrNE&export=download")

# create lookup table
lookup <- data.table(pickup_name = c("Safeway", "Whole Foods Market", "Pizzeria Delfina"),
                     pickup_zipcode = c(94107, 94107, 94110),
                     label = c("-H2", "-H1", "-H3")
)

# join with lookup table and update on join
DT[lookup, on = .(pickup_name, pickup_zipcode), pickup_name := paste0(pickup_name, label)]

# verify data are updated
DT[pickup_name %like% "-H.$", .(pickup_name, pickup_zipcode)]
```

> ```
>                 pickup_name pickup_zipcode
>    1:            Safeway-H2          94107
>    2: Whole Foods Market-H1          94107
>    3:            Safeway-H2          94107
>    4: Whole Foods Market-H1          94107
>    5: Whole Foods Market-H1          94107
>   ---                                     
> 2003:            Safeway-H2          94107
> 2004: Whole Foods Market-H1          94107
> 2005:            Safeway-H2          94107
> 2006:   Pizzeria Delfina-H3          94110
> 2007: Whole Foods Market-H1          94107
> ```

`fread` reads data directly from Google Drive using [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33142446/3817004). `DT` has about 60 K rows and 22 columns (about 9 MB on disk).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a `data.table`  approach. You may have to install data.table library:

```
library(data.table)
dat<-data.table(problem)
setkey(dat, pickup_zipcode, pickup_name)
dat[J(94107, "Safeway"), pickup_name:="Safeway-H2"]
setkey(dat, pickup_zipcode, pickup_name)
dat[J(94107, "Whole Foods Market"), pickup_name:="Whole Foods Market-H1"]
setkey(dat, pickup_zipcode, pickup_name)
dat[J(94110, "Pizzeria Delfina"), pickup_name:="Pizzeria Delfina-H3"]
```

Comment: Hi Jean. I typed what you showed up there and changed the variable names. But it says that it could not find the function. setkey(problem, pickup_zipcode, pickup_name)
problem[J(94107, "Safeway"), pickup_name:="Safeway-H2"]
problem[J(94107, "Whole Foods Market"), pickup_name:="Whole Foods Market-H1"]
problem[J(94110, "Pizzeria Delfina"), pickup_name:="Pizzeria Delfina-H3"]

Comment: You need to install data.table package. Try running this first: 

install.packages("data.table", dep=T);
library(data.table)

Comment: I ran all the codes and the it says   "Error in `[.data.table`(dat, J(94107, "Whole Foods Market"), `:=`(pickup_name,  : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified either using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table) or by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM."

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you run 

dput(head(problem)) 

and paste the output here: So we'll have a sample data to see the error.

Comment: It was quite long but the headers are:  customer_price courier_price, day_of_week_local service, market num_items, pickup_zipcode, distance_pickup_to_dropoff_km, purchase_price avg_courier_rating,   status duration reassigned dropoff_zipcode, rating_by_customer purchase_feevehicle_type, pickup_name purchase_tip credit_applied,             date_created_local,rating_by_courier

Comment: I can't think of any reasons why the code I provided wouldn't work. Can you check class(dat[,pickup_zipcode]) to see if it is integer/numeric, and also class(dat[,pickup_name]) to see if it is character. Like MrFlick mentioned, without a reproducible example we can't troubleshoot your code.

Comment: Hi Jean. I am afraid that I was not super clear on the question. So below are the links to the requirement of the question and dataset. Really appreciate you being so patient!

Comment: data - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DEdJvAdACVv_Pc5IcgFBSGvDKm_GPrNE

Comment: requirement https://drive.google.com/open?id=119axqgvRZikM-nfV0C8MFl6RyEXgFXYC. Let me go ahead check and read the link MrFlick gave. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. The first one is zip code is numeric(integer) and the name is character.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try running the code now - it looks like setkey has to be run everytime after assigning a change, which I wasn't aware!!

Comment: @JeanVuda Best practice is to use the `on =` argument, even if you're sure the data.table has a key.  This prevents odd errors from popping up (like above) and makes the code more explicit in what's happening.

Comment: @Nathan Werth, I am not sure how to use on argument. Do you have an example?

Comment: `dat[J(94107, "Safeway"), on = c("pickup_zipcode", "pickup_name"), pickup_name:="Safeway-H2"]`.  Just a character vector doing the same job as the key, but without the assumption a key exists.  If the key does exist, then it will be used, so setting keys still gives a performance boost.

Comment: That setting key thing seems a glitch. Because I was able to run this without getting any error. But I get your point and it is much nicer code too.
<code>
dt <- data.table(c(1,2,3,4,5),c("chr1","chr1","chr2","chr3","chr4"),c(12,12,13,14,15));
setkey(dt, V1, V2);
dt[J(2, "chr1"),V3:=20] ;
dt[J(1, "chr1"),V3:=10] ;
dt[J(5, "chr4"),V3:=40] ;
</code>

Comment: I edited the code as suggested and it looks like this now library(data.table)
 dat<-data.table(problem)
 setkey(dat, pickup_zipcode, pickup_name)
 dat[J(94107, "Safeway"), on = c("pickup_zipcode", "pickup_name"), pickup_name:="Safeway-H2"]