# readRDS from url

Tags: r, https, onedrive

I saved a dataset in a `RDS` file on onedrive  and made it shareable [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am3aUTxhPMS8iM4pqe5fUZbiA4m9rw). Now, if I use that link to read the file, I got an error.

```
readRDS(url("https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am3aUTxhPMS8iM4pqe5fUZbiA4m9rw"))
#> Error in readRDS(url("https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am3aUTxhPMS8iM4pqe5fUZbiA4m9rw")): unknown input format
```

On the other hand, if I download the file from the browser, I copy the link address and I use that one...that  works.

Unfortunately, the link address obtained in that way is **available only for a limited time** (it doesn't work permanently).

I know `googledrive` and `rdrop2` and so I have some workarounds,
but still...I don't understand the logic behind this. 
Any help?

Comment: shouldn't you use `readRDS`?

Comment: My apologies, I meant to write readRDS...

Comment: does this link do some sort of redirection? try downloading the url without any redirections or scripts, e.g. by using curl.

Comment: Search on the internet, you'll find how to generate a direct downloadable link for a one drive file... Last I remember , copy and customize the the `iframe` link will do that, which you can call from your rscript.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither those solutions work. In both cases you end up downloading a string ( "/var/folders/yc/gsp94d0x6nvcgb__spc0p6lm0000gn/T//RtmpkGptu4/filebad934576c0a", the path on the server?) and not the actual file. I think we need something along the lines of what @lukeA has shown for gdrive here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135060/read-csv-file-hosted-on-google-drive#33142446)

Comment: I tried to adapt that example to onedrive but I was unsuccessful